# Laravel get all records where the date in one column is 7days less or equal to the date in another column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two date columns in a table, created_at and encountered_at. I want to get all rows where encountered_at is 1 week less than created_at. How do I go about it without doing any looping?

This is an example

```
id | encountered_at | created_at   
1  | 2020-04-17     | 2020-04-23  
2  | 2020-04-17     | 2020-04-24   
3  | 2020-04-17     | 2020-11-29
```

the first two records should show up. I guess this is straigt in SQL, how do I achieve this with Eloquent?
...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it using [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods)  and [dateDiff](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php) ....

```
$result=MyModelClass::whereRaw('DATEDIFF(created_at,encountered_at)<=7')
select('*')->get();
```

please note that the result here will contains the rows where the diff if less or equal than 7 days ... if you want it to be only 7 days you can just omit '<' ....

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to `SELECT * FROM table WHERE "DIFF OF encountered_at AND created_at LESS THAN 1 Week"` - so you want to calculate the difference and then test it to be less than a week. I recommend the following mysql doc-page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: Thanks for the resource.

Answer (score 0):

The `whereBetween` method verifies that a column's value is between two values.

```
$from = date('2020-01-01');
$to = date('2020-05-02');
Model::whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->get();
```

You can check date between two dates using carbon object.You can get current date then start date and end date between date then return true otherwise false return.

```
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2020-10-01');
$endDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2020-10-30');
$check = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->between($startDate,$endDate);
dd($check); // return true or false
```